# Установка zabbix 3.2 на CentOS 7

Tags: linux, zabbix

После установки zabbix 3.2 на web server apache возникает ошибка проверки:

`Minimum required limit on execution time of PHP scripts is 300 (configuration option "max_execution_time")
PHP option "max_execution_time" 60   300    Fail`.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

В конфигах `/etc/PHP_VERSION/apache/php.ini` надо найти:`max_execution_time`
и установить значение `300`.

Comment: поставил, проблема не ушла

Comment: sudo service apache2 restart (рестарт апач сервера, чтобы применить настройки)

Comment: спасибо, конечно делал рестарт

Answer (score 0):

посмотри, может ты не в том php.ini правишь ? есть вероятность, что он у тебя не один.

```
sudo grep max_execution_time `sudo find / -name php.ini`
```

ну и ещё посмотри файл /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 300
    php_value memory_limit 128M
    ...
```